# Magento 1.8.1 - Remove "Edit" from cart

Tags: php, magento

I have this annoying Edit link in the cart:

[image: Edit link]

It looks nasty and affects the table layout, yet I can't figure out where to remove it.

If I go here:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/xyz/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

And comment out line 141:

```
<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
```

The table disappears, so it is obviously generated from this line.  However I can't figure out where getItemHtml pulls it's data from.

I've found other websites that suggest this file is responsible:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/xyz/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

However if I rename that file it makes no difference.  I've also tried the verison in `/base/` but with no luck.

Any ideas?

====

Edit, here is the code of default.phtml:

```
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
?>
<?php $one_item=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId()); ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(88,94); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>"></a>
    </td>
    <?php if($one_item->getBrand()) $add_brand=$one_item->getAttributeText('brand'); else $add_brand='';  ?>
    <?php if($one_item->getProductSize()) $add_type=$one_item->getAttributeText('product_size'); else $add_type=''; ?>
    <td>
        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><strong><?php echo $add_brand; ?></strong> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?> <?php echo $add_type; ?></a></h2>
    </td>
    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
        <td>
            <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getMoveFromCartUrl($_item->getId()); ?>" class="link-wishlist use-ajax"><?php echo $this->__('Move'); ?></a>
            <?php endif ?>
        </td>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
        <td>
            <span class="cart-price">
                <span class="cart-msrp-unit"><?php echo $this->__('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>
                <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                <a id="<?php echo $helpLinkId ?>" href="#" class="map-help-link"><?php echo $this->__("What's this?"); ?></a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    Catalog.Map.addHelpLink($('<?php echo $helpLinkId ?>'), "<?php echo $this->__("What's this?") ?>");
                </script>
            </span>
        </td>
    <?php else: ?>

        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <td>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </span>


            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

                <div class="cart-tax-info" id="eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <td>
            <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item); ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </span>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

                <div class="cart-tax-info" id="unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()); ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td>
        <div class="input-number td qty" data-max="999" data-min="0">
            <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="form-control input-text qty" maxlength="12" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php if (($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()) && !$_item->getNoSubtotal()): ?>
    <td>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart-msrp-subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </span>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()) && !$_item->getNoSubtotal()): ?>
    <td>
        <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getSubtotalInclTax($_item); ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart-msrp-subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </span>


        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td>
        <div class="td last"><a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?></a></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

====

Edit2, here is the HTML of the offending table cell:

```
<td class="a-center">
  <a href="http://stage.mywebsite.co.uk/checkout/cart/configure/id/272/" title="Edit item parameters">Edit</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for:

```
\app\design\frontend\[package]\default\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml
```

Thats the template for `getItemHtml($_item)` in cart.

You should find the edit button there. If you show me the code I could even remove that for you

Comment: Hi, that file doesn't contain the edit link and if I rename it (or move it / delete it) it makes no difference - very confusing as I had thought it used that file too...  do you want to see the entire code of default.phtml?

Comment: Do you try to edit it in base or in your own package?

Comment: I have removed both the base and the package versions.  There is no caching on this website (it is the development area) and after multiple refreshes the table still exists

Comment: So for me this path:
C:\Users\fischer\Documents\www\trunk\htdocs\app\design\frontend\[company_name]\default\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml worked (for deleting the quantity as i have no edit button)

Comment: I've added the code of default.phtml to the original question.  It is from the package, just like the url you provided

Comment: This whishlist thing doesnt seem to be the edit button although you could give it a try to delete it. Best way to search for things is spectating the edit element with google or firefox developer tools, find a hopefully unique class/id/[...] at the element you want to find and use "Find in files" feature the most IDEs provide. Thats not the cleanest but probably the fastest way

Comment: I've inspected the Edit link and added the HTML to the original question.  I'm not sure how to use the "Find in files" you suggest but will have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82787/discussion-between-sidiastudios-and-lee).

Comment: /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php line 204 contains code 'checkout/cart/configure' which suggests maybe this is where it is generated